# Finding the distribution of $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\Big( \sum_i^m (X_i-\bar{X})^2+\sum_j^m (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 \Big)$ where $X_i$ is from a normal sample

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_m$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be independent random samples from normal distributions $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$, $N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$ respectively, where all parameters are unknown.

Let
$$S^2=(m+n-2)^{-1}\Big( \sum_i^m (X_i-\bar{X})^2+\sum_j^m (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 \Big)$$

Can anyone help me find the distributions of:

$$(m+n-2)S^2/\sigma^2\tag{1}$$
And
$$\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{S^2(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n})}}\tag{2}$$

For $(2)$ I am having no real luck at all. With $(1)$ I have the obvious step of writing
$$(m+n-2)S^2/\sigma^2=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\Big( \sum_i^m (X_i-\bar{X})^2+\sum_j^m (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 \Big)$$
On the RHS is there some connection with the variance of $X$ and $Y$?

$$(m+n-2)S^2/\sigma^2=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\Big( \frac{\alpha^2}{m-1}+\frac{\beta^2}{n-1}\Big)$$
Where $\alpha^2,\beta^2$ are the sample variance for $X$ and $Y$ which we can relate to the addition of 2 chi square distributions? i.e. $\chi_{m-1}^2+\chi_{n-1}^2=\chi_{m+n-2}^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation $\sum_j^m (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$ is a bit odd.  Maybe you meant $\sum_{j=1}^m (Y_j-\bar{Y})^2$ or $\sum_1^m (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$?

Anyway, if you know that
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1},
$$
(and you seem to suggest that you do know that) then exactly the same reasoning leads to
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^m (Y_i - \bar Y)^2 \sim \chi^2_{m-1},
$$
and then, since they're independent, their sum is distributed at $\chi^2_{n+m-2}$.

The numerator in (2) is distributed as $N\left( 0, \dfrac{\sigma^2}{n} + \dfrac{\sigma^2}{m} \right)$.  So that numerator divided by $\sigma$ is distibuted as $N\left( 0, \dfrac 1n + \dfrac 1m\right)$.  Hence that numerator divided by $\sigma\sqrt{\dfrac 1n + \dfrac 1m}$ is distributed as $N(0,1)$.  Since you've divided by $\sigma$ both on top and on the bottom, the $\sigma$ cancels out and you've actually got a *statistic*, i.e. a random variable whose value can be found by knowing the $X$s and the $Y$s without knowing $\sigma$ or the $\mu$s.

Hence you've got
$$
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\chi^2/\mathrm{d.f.}}}.
$$
Moreover (the harder part, maybe?) the numerator and denominator are independent.  To see that, notice that $(\bar X, X_i-\bar X)$ are not merely a pair of normally distributed random variables, but the pair is *jointly* normally distributed, since both components are linear combinations of the same set of independent normals.  That implies they're independent if they're uncorrelated.  So compute their covariance.

Consequently, you've got a Student's t-distribution.

Comment: This is brilliant! thanks very much :)